# Install Windows XP (or Vista) on iMac

Tags: windows, mac

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you run ONLY Windows on a mac?](https://superuser.com/questions/50841/can-you-run-only-windows-on-a-mac)

Is it possible to install Windows XP or Windows Vista on iMac without major headache and without paying for anything but a Windows license? I believe it's an Intel machine.

I don't need dual boot option. We don't want to see MacOSX anymore.

P.S. "Why would you want to install Windows if iMAC is far more [...]?" is not an acceptable answer. Windows is far more [...], to be honest.

Comment: There's no easy way to only have Windows on a Mac; it's been discussed in another question on SuperUser.

Comment: Duplicate - http://superuser.com/questions/50841/can-you-run-only-windows-on-a-mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find out more about installing Windows on a Mac in this [Apple support page](http://www.apple.com/support/bootcamp/). You need to use Boot Camp Assistant to install Windows without major headaches.

The prerequisites are an Intel based Mac, a USB keyboard and mouse and 10GB of free space (plus the Windows CD or DVD). To install:

> - Back up the important information on
>     your computer.
> - Open Boot Camp Assistant (located in
>     the Utilities folder in the
>     Applications folder).
> - Print and follow the instructions in
>     the “Boot Camp Installation & Setup
>     Guide.”

Comment: Glad it helped you out. Enjoy Windows on your iMac!

Answer (score 1):

I have an iMac 24" from February 2009, with Intel platform. As "MicTech" just wrote, you can install Windows on the whole HDD, and erase the Mac OS partition, like I did. 
It works really fine, the drivers being on the original Apple CD.

I just had to look a bit for a recent Grafic driver, for some new games and application.

If you use BootCamp, it's nice also, but you still use half of your HDD for Mac OS, and you have to choose at boot on wich system you'd like to boot.

So you just insert the Windows CD/DVD in the drive, reboot and press "ALT" until a boot screen shows. Choose the CD, and then you probably know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

If iMac is Intel platform then you can install XP. Maybe you will have some issues with drivers for iMac hardware.

Comment: So, do I just put in the Windows installation disk and go on with installation? (Haven't tried because I haven't backed up the computer yet)