# Can I erase OS X after I installed Windows with Boot Camp?

Tags: windows-xp, mac, boot-camp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove Mac OS X and install Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/73965/remove-mac-os-x-and-install-windows)

I installed Windows XP on my Mac with Boot Camp, and now I want to erase OS X. Is it possible?

Comment: So... you bought a Mac, and you're just going to run Windows on it? Couldn't you have saved a lot of money and just bought a cheaper non-mac laptop?

Comment: WHY??? Why-o-why would someone misuse an Apple computer for Windows? It's like adding two more wheels to your motorbike to change it into a car. If you want a car, but a car.

Comment: @Jasarien Buying Mac hardware gives you the option of switching to OSX down the line. They might also just like the design/build care.

Comment: Several reasons for all those who keep asking why oh why????
 
1. I owned at least 10 windows machines HP, DELL, ASUS, TOSHIBA, SONY other crap. all of those just dies in 2-3 years. DIES MEANING .....D I E S. Will not boot. COLD DEAD!!
2. Macs although expensive will always last and last and even with "inferior" hardware, will kick any windows machine's ass. 
3. I have several other Macs in my house, but I am a Microsoft Developer, and I used to dual boot for development all the time on my speedy laptop, but I started running out of disk space, because I had only 128G hdd on my MBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this [thread](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=195187):

> All Boot Camp is, is a glorified
>   partitioner (well, the drivers are the
>   key). Once you have the drivers, you
>   could quit out of boot camp and
>   install XP and erase and reformat the
>   entire drive as NTSF.
>
> The BIOS compatibility in EFI comes
>   from the firmware update, which is
>   required to run Boot Camp, which is a
>   setup assistant that burns a drivers
>   CD and partitions your drive. You only
>   need the firmware update to run
>   Windows, but Apple won't tell you that

And from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/50841/can-you-run-only-windows-on-a-mac):

> Boot Camp drivers are used for things
>   like the Apple keyboards, trackpads,
>   mice, special function keys for
>   brightness, etc. to function in
>   Windows. You can download a version of
>   the Boot Camp drivers from Apple's
>   website, but it is only an update and
>   doesn't include the full suite of
>   drivers and device software. Since the
>   full Boot Camp software is on the OS X
>   disc, you will need a copy of the OS X
>   on-hand, but you don't have to have to
>   keep OS X installed.

Which seems to mean that once all the firmware and drivers were installed, you can erase the OSX partition and reformat it for use by Windows.

Comment: actually, the Boot Camp drivers are on the Mac OS X DVD and need to be installed once Windows' set up is complete. I think they have to be seen as something different from the actual "Boot Camp Boot Loader"... In the end, it doesn't tell what is going to happen if you remove the Mac partition!

Comment: A test can be done using a free partition manager such as GParted to hide the OSX partition. If this works, then it can be recycled. If not, unhiding it will fix the problem, maybe followed by shrinking it to the minimum possible to recuperate maximum space. The later is what I would counsel doing, keeping OSX around just in case.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is that simple. [See that other question for a complete tutorial.](https://superuser.com/questions/73965/remove-mac-os-x-and-install-windows)